# if $p = charD \ \ $ then $ px = 0 \ \ \ \forall x \in D $.

Tags: proof-verification, ring-theory, integral-domain

The characteristic of an integral domain D is defined as:

$charD := min\{ n \in \mathbb{N} :  na = 0 , \text{for some} \   0 \neq  a \in D  \} $

I want to prove that if  $p = charD \ \ $ then $ px = 0 \ \ \  \forall x \in D $.

Here's my attempt.
Let $ 0 \neq a\in D\ \ $ such that $pa = 0 $ this implies that 
$$(pa)x = (a+a+\cdots +a)x = (ax+ax+\cdots +ax) = \\ a(x+x+\cdots+ x) = a(px) = 0$$  $\forall x \in D $ then $px = 0 \ \ $ since $a\neq 0$

what do you think, is it correct?...if it's not, how would you do it?. 
Thank you.

Comment: I think that is pretty damn good!

Comment: @RobertLewis “This single fact is so compelling that it motivates one to try, despite the above-mentioned technological difficulties, to develop browser-compatible presentations of ever-increasing utility, integrity of form, and asthetic appeal.” **I dig it!** The way you interpret formatting and articulate yourself resonates with me strongly. This is my new favourite website.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor:  where did that quote come from?  I really dig it!

Comment: @RobertLewis It came from your website!

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor:  wow!  I thought it sounded familiar!  http://www.fuckyeah.biz/webeye.htm!  I went back and checked it out again.  Thanks for the reminder; I haven't worked on it in a few  years . . .

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor:  you mean fuckyeah.biz is your new favorite?

Comment: @RobertLewis fo’ sho’

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor:  that is awesome dude!  Maybe I'll start working on it again . . .